# Examples of programming language affecting the english language

Tags: programming

I'm a programmer. I'm told I often use 'else' like the *if ... else* statement in a programming language. For example, this text message I sent yesterday:

> Hey, *if* you haven't had lunch wanna go to the tavern? *Else* [do you want to see] the latest Hobbit movie?

- Is this sentence grammatically correct?
- Are there any examples of where a programming language has influenced or changed the English language?

Comment: You're not even using *else* the way it is used in programming.  You're using more like "*On a completely separate note...*"

Comment: @Jim perhaps a poor example. The logic is there, just implied.

Comment: so if your friend responded with, "Yes, I saw it last night.'  How would you proceed with the conversation?

Comment: @Jim I'll just change the bloody question.

Comment: I can't see how this doesn't bear out an _if…else_ relation (even before the edit). _If_ (you haven't had lunch) { wanna go to the tavern? } else if (you have had lunch) { have you seen / wanna go see the movie? }. @Jim, if anyone answered “Yes, I saw it last night” (to the original question), I would assume they had already had lunch, and they therefore answered the _else_ question, so I'd suggest a different movie instead for example. Seems perfectly logical to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Me, I’m a touch surprised that so many people appear to consider *else* used as a synonym for *otherwise* to be ungrammatical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet- You have properly parsed it as a programming *else*.  I just have a feeling that if someone were to do that in casual conversation the asker would likely think, "Ok, but you haven't answered my question about lunch, do you wanna go or not."

Comment: I'm surprised no one's mentioned FORTRAN's effect on Shakespeare; his frequent use of GO TO is an example. _Go to, I’ll no more on ’t. It hath made me mad._ (Hamlet, Act 3, Scene 1). As we all know, GO TO is now considered harmful, and its seed was planted at about the same time as the seed of commercial tobacco, which is also now considered harmful.

Comment: Applying propositional logic to natural language seems to be a programming influence. As in nerds who answer questions like "Did that site crash on its own, or were you doing something on the server that caused it to?" with "Yes"

Comment: !likely; // character count food

Answer (score 3):

Some obvious points: 1) the wording you used in your text message is not evidence of a wider phenomenon, and 2) the logic of an *if...else* programming statement is not manifested in your message.

Regarding your question about the grammaticality of "Else have you seen the latest Hobbit movie?" the answer is that it isn't, because you are using 'else' in a grammatically non-standard way.

I'm unaware of a programming language having influenced English other than through the coining of domain-related terminology; thankfully, nobody I know structures their everyday speech like a computer program.

Comment: I have seen people who always put a "then", in sentences that start with "if" , even where "then" is not called for by any convention of English grammar.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - Maybe so, but the linguistic influence has been in the opposite direction: the logic of "if...then" has been adopted by programmers from an existing English usage, not *vice versa*. That being the case, it would be rather difficult to demonstrate that the inclusion of an optional 'then' was the direct result of an influence emanating from a programming practice.

Comment: Edited the question to satisfy 2)

Comment: Your second sentence is incorrect. Please check the OED, where it has clear citations for this use.

Comment: That use of "Else" is not non-standard. It is a bit archaic though.

Answer (score 1):

### *Else* = *Otherwise*

The question of grammaticality is yes.  OED sense 4 covers this, and it has four subsenses:

> 4. **a.** In another case, under other circumstances; otherwise, on any other supposition; if not.
>
>    **b.**  preceded by *or*. Also <sub><sup>**OR ELSE**</sup></sub>, with aposiopesis (the alternative to be imagined), as a colloq. form of warning or threat.
>
>    **c.** idiomatically. = ‘If it is not believed’. Now *rare* or *dial*.
>
>    **d.** qualifying an adj. *rhetorical*.

And here are a couple of its citations for 4a:

> - 1837 J. H. Newman *Par. Serm*. (ed. 3) I. v. 115 ― Else how should any one be saved?
> - 1873 Browning *Red Cott. Night-C.* 115 ― Boughs above, Darken, deform the path, else sun would streak.

So *else* can indeed start an independent clause, in which case it means *otherwise*.  This is grammatical.

### *Else* = *Elsewise*

In this sense, *else* is equivalent to *elsewise*, which per the OED means:

> In some other manner; in other circumstances, otherwise.

One of the citations for using *elsewise* in this way is from the last novel of Charles Dickens:

> 1865 Dickens *Our Mutual Friend* I. 97 ― Elsewise the world got up at eight.

So you could use *elsewise* instead of just plain *else*, but that one might get you talked about, since some people don’t realize it’s even a word.  Then again, apparently you already get flack for using *else* in a grammatical way as though it were some sort of violation of grammar when it is not.